# Did labialized consonants remain in Ryūkyūan?

Tags: phonology, wago-and-kango, phonetics, ryukyuan-languages

The [labialized velar consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labialized_velar_consonant) are rare even in historical Japanese; besides (possibly) one verb (*kweru*), they (*kwa-*, *gwa-*, *kwe-*, *gwe-*) occur only in some Sino-Japanese morphemes. In Japanese, they merged with the non-labialized versions (*ka-*, *ga-*, *ke-*, *ge-*) as late as the early 20th Century.

But do they remain in Ryūkyūan?

Or, did they even exist in Ryūkyūan? Obviously, Ryūkyūan also borrowed multiple Sino-Xenic terms, some of which must have been necessarily present: such as name of the goddess Kwannon. Do we know the current status of words like this? Even if such words are Sino-Japanese borrowed from Japanese, did the labiovelars remain in Ryūkyūan even when, very recently, Japanese stopped pronouncing them with the //-w-// glide? Unfortunately, the vast corpus of scholarly work, to my knowledge, rarely deals with the Sinitic layer in Ryūkyūan.

Comment: Surely these are labiovelar *consonants*?

Comment: Surely. Edited!

Comment: FWIW, modern 蹴る【ける】 shows up as older くゑる, but there the くゑ were the full kana sound values //ku// + //we//.  This verb くゑる was the 下二段活用【しもにだんかつよう】 derivation of older ワ行【ぎょう】-conjugation verb くう.  Confusingly, the ゑ kana also apparently represented //je// instead of //we//, and there is old evidence of a くゆ form for this same "to kick" verb.  At any rate, I can't find any verb //kweru//.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After poking around a bit in the Shuri-Naha Dialect Dictionary that covers the Okinawan branch of Ryūkyūan, it appears that here, at least, labiovelars did persist.  A sampling of entries that show maintained labiovelars:

- [クヮンジミ](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN11879), Japanese 缶詰【かんづめ】
- [クェーチウイウェー](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN11122), Japanese 快気【かいき】祝【いわ】い
- [クヮンヌン](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN11888), Japanese 観音【かんのん】
- [カングヮーシ](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN50495), apparently equivalent to Japanese 羊羹【ようかん】 + 菓子【かし】; the entry also mentions ムイグヮーシ with a given kanji spelling of 盛菓子.
- [グェーシチ](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN11116), Japanese 外戚【がいせき】
- [クェーテー](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN11124), Japanese 懐胎【かいたい】

I did find a term where Japanese dictionaries indicate an older //gwa-// pronunciation, but Okinawan doesn't reflect the labiovelar.

- [ガンジュー](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN10780), Japanese 頑丈【がんじょう】

This appears to be an exception to the rule, however, which raises the question of whether this was a later borrowing from Japanese, rather than an older import when the kanji term was borrowed from Middle Chinese.

Notably, the labiovelars I can find reflected in Okinawan are all traceable to older //kwa-// or //gwa-//.  The //kwe-// and //gwe-// variants found in Japanese appear to have undergone different sound shifts in Okinawan, such that the labiovelar was apparently lost.  One clear example I could find was [トゥチー](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN22336), cognate with Japanese 時計【とけい】.  The likely original, Chinese-derived spelling was 土圭, and 圭 apparently had an older reading of //kwei//.  So it seems that the //kwe-// labiovelars may have shifted first to something like //ki-//, and then underwent the regular change to become affricate //t͡ʃi-// (incidentally, much like the pronunciation of ⟨ci⟩ went from Latin //ki// to Italian //t͡ʃi//).

---

Please comment if the above does not fully address your question.